# Cannot Post to php script Angular 2

Tags: php, http, angular, typescript

I am trying to use a post request to a php script, which contains data I need.

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserComment } from '../definition/user.comment';
import { HomeService } from '../services/home.service';
import { DbService } from '../services/db.service';
import { Trip } from '../definition/trip';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './templates/home.html',
    providers: [HomeService, DbService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    user_comments: UserComment[];
    trips: Trip[];

    constructor(private homeService: HomeService, private dbService: DbService) { }

    getUserComments(): void {
        this.homeService.getData().then(user_comments => this.user_comments = user_comments);
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getUserComments();
        console.log(this.dbService.getTrips('test').subscribe());
    }
}
```

In the `ngOnInit` the `getTrips()` function from my `DbService` will be called, which looks like this.

```
import { Injectable }                              from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions}  from '@angular/http';
import { Trip }                                    from '../definition/trip';
import { Observable }                              from 'rxjs/Rx';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class DbService {

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    private dbUrl = '../apis/db_api.php';  // URL to web API

    getTrips(name): Observable<Response> {
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        let body = JSON.stringify(name);
        return this.http.post(this.dbUrl, body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

This would be the php file

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'route_name' => 'test',
    'route_info' => 'test info',
    'rating' => 2.5,
    'coordinates' => '9838e901',
    'is_active' => 1,
    'deleted_at' => NULL
);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

When I do that, I get the following error in the console

[image: error]

This would be the project structure

[image: folder structure]

The weird thing is when I change the post to a get, I get the JSON string of the php file.

The Idea would be to have a php file which is commuicating with the local database, to return data, but for now I just hardcoded the data in the php file.

Would appreciate the help

Regards

Comment: Shouldn't the url be `'../apis/db_api.php'`?

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to change it back even with .php its the same error, I updated the question and the error picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with you code is you are calling this.http.post with relative url.first you have to install Apache web server and php in your system if you want run it locally. and your complete project should be under Apache web directory like all our php projects

```
private dbUrl = '../apis/db_api.php';  // URL to web API
```

your private dbUrl is wrong. php files works only on server side. so there should be complete address of your file location after localhost. like this

```
 var Path="http://localhost/amit/login/server/login.php";
```

add localhost in your url then include location of your db_api file. if you have uploaded your code on some server then use there address in place of localhost. You are calling a http request which should go to a server.

so your dbUrl should be like private dbUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/tripahead/apis/db_api.php';

```
 @Injectable()
export class DbService {

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    private dbUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/tripahead/apis/db_api.php'; <-- location of your server php file location. 

    getTrips(name): Observable<Response> {
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        let body = JSON.stringify(name);
        return this.http.post(this.dbUrl, body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay well I had the full path before, and it was not working, but as I read your answer I realised I have my php file not running on any server or xamp or anything its just in the project, so that might be the problem right?

Comment: sir first you have to install Apache web server and php in your system if you want run it locally. and your complete project should be under Apache web directory like all our php projects. then it will work :)

Comment: the error that you got is 404 file not found.http://localhost:3000/tripahead/apis/db_api.php <-- see add location from your apache directory to your php file.

Comment: Yes I moved the php file into my ampps directory where my php server is running and now its working thank you very much, If you create an answer  I can accept It if you want